# How can I set a foreign key to allow nulls using ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack v4.x VS2013

By default ServiceStack ORMLite (SqlServer) defines foreign keys with "NOT NULL".
The following code produces a foreign key "FooId (FK, long, not null)"
How can I tell ServiceStack this foreign key may be null?

```
public class Blah
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Foo))]
    public long FooId { get; set; }

}

public class Foo
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a value type is nullable in OrmLite, make it nullable in C#:

```
public class Blah
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Foo))]
    public long? FooId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things that elude you!   Thanks @mythz!